# Remove PostGIS 1.3.3 From Database

Tags: postgis

Trying to upgrade some databases from 8.3 to 9.1.  In the database dumps are a lot of postgis functions like this that reference postgis files

```
CREATE FUNCTION st_box2d_in(cstring) RETURNS box2d
AS '/usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/lib/liblwgeom', 'BOX2DFLOAT4_in'
LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Is there a utility to uninstall all postgis 1.3.3  column types, functions etc from a database?

Comment: Do you have installed on you system a script called `uninstall_postgis.sql` ?

Comment: I don't see a file like that.  Checked the postgis and postgresql-8.3-postgis package listings.  This is on debian Lenny, trying to move to new server.